# KnockOut.JS populate dropdown with value from observable

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, knockout.js

I have view and bindings using knockout and I am trying to populate my dropdown menus with the values in my observable array but my html is somehow overriding it and displaying the default string instead.

**My HTML**

```
  <table id="tblBrands">
        <tr data-bind="foreach: agency">

            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Advertiser Name
                        </td>
                        <td>Account Name
                        </td>
                        <td>Responsibility
                        </td>
                        <td>Full Name
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tbody data-bind="foreach: brands">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input data-bind="value: advertiserName" /></td>

                            <td>
                                <input data-bind="value: brandName" /></td>

                            <td>
                               <!-- <select data-bind="value: responsibility" />-->



                                <select data-bind="value: responsibility">
                                    <option value="">Select...</option>
                                    <option value="">Media Manager</option>
                                    <option value="">Strategic Responsibility</option>
                                    <option value="">Planning/Buying</option>
                                </select>

                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <input data-bind="value: fullName" /></td>

                            <td><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removeBrand' style="color: blue">Remove</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </table>
```

I am trying to bind this to a dropdown menu:

```
<select data-bind="value: responsibility">
```

**Agency JS**

My agency viewmodel is quite big but this is how it works:

```
define(['services/datacontext'], function (dataContext) {
    var initialized = false;
    var agency;


    agency = ko.observableArray([]);

    var save = function () {
        // Clear Cache because user submitted the form. We don't have to hold onto data anymore.
        localStorage.setItem('Agency', null);
        localStorage.setItem('Offices', null);
        localStorage.setItem('Brands', null);

        var agency = ko.toJS(vm.agency._latestValue[0]) //Drill down to _latestValue and convert this to standard JS object

        var s = YUI().use("json-stringify", function (Y) {
            var jsonAgency = Y.JSON.stringify(agency, [
                "activities",
                "agencyName",
                "agencyID",
                "category",
                "declaredBillings",
                "immediateParent",
                "numberOfEmployees",
                "ultimateParent",
                "uRL",
                "offices",
                "address1",
                "address2",
                "address3",
                "address4",
                "address5",
                "agencyID",
                "faxNumber",
                "officeID",
                "postCode",
                "telephoneNumber",
                "contacts",
                "emailAddress",
                "firstName",
                "jobName",
                "personID",
                "surName",
                "title",
                "brands",
                "agencyId",
                "brandId",
                "brandName",
                "categoryDescription",
                "dateAmended",
                "activities",
                "additionalInfo",
                "advertiserId",
                "advertiserName",
                "alfRank",
                "cinemaRank",
                "directMailRank",
                "internetRank",
                "nielsenId",
                "notes",
                "numberOfEmployees",
                "outdoorRank",
                "pressRank",
                "radioRank",
                "tVRank"
            ]);
            dataContext.saveChanges(jsonAgency, localStorage.setItem('AgencyCurrent', jsonAgency)); // Pass current data from cache and new data from form

        })
    }

    var vm = { // This is my view model, my functions are bound to it. 
        //These are wired up to my agency view
        activate: activate,
        agency: agency,
        title: 'agency',
        refresh: refresh, // call refresh function which calls get Agencies
        save: save,
        cacheForm: cacheForm,
        addOffice: addOffice,
        removeOffice: removeOffice,
        addBrand: addBrand,
        removeBrand: removeBrand,
        addContact: addContact,
        removeContact: removeContact
    };
    return vm;

    function activate() {
        vm.agency;
        if (initialized) {
            return;
        }
        initialized = false;
        refresh();
    }

    function refresh() {
        dataContext.getAgency(agency);
    }


    function cacheForm(agency) {

        var agency = ko.toJS(vm.agency._latestValue[0]) //Drill down to _latestValue and convert this to standard JS object

        //Check if the current data has been cached before caching the new data, otherwise just cache the new data.
        if (!localStorage.AgencyCurrent) {
            var s = YUI().use("json-stringify", function (Y) {
                var jsonAgency = Y.JSON.stringify(agency, [
                    "activities",
                    "agencyName",
                    "agencyID",
                    "campaignBillings",
                    "category",
                    "declaredBillings",
                    "immediateParent",
                    "numberOfEmployees",
                    "ultimateParent",
                    "uRL",
                    "offices",
                    "address1",
                    "address2",
                    "address3",
                    "address4",
                    "address5",
                    "agencyID",
                    "faxNumber",
                    "officeID",
                    "postCode",
                    "telephoneNumber",
                    "contacts",
                    "emailAddress",
                    "firstName",
                    "jobName",
                    "personID",
                    "surName",
                    "title",
                    "brands",
                    "agencyId",
                    "brandId",
                    "brandName",
                    "categoryDescription",
                    "dateAmended",
                    "activities",
                    "additionalInfo",
                    "advertiserId",
                    "advertiserName",
                    "alfRank",
                    "cinemaRank",
                    "directMailRank",
                    "internetRank",
                    "nielsenId",
                    "notes",
                    "numberOfEmployees",
                    "outdoorRank",
                    "pressRank",
                    "radioRank",
                    "tVRank"
                ]);
                localStorage.setItem('AgencyCurrent', null);
                localStorage.setItem('AgencyCurrent', jsonAgency);
            }) 
        }

        var brands = ko.toJS(vm.brands);

        var s = YUI().use("json-stringify", function (Y) {
            var jsonStrAgency = Y.JSON.stringify(agency, [
                "activities",
                "agencyName",
                "agencyID",
                "campaignBillings",
                "category",
                "declaredBillings",
                "immediateParent",
                "numberOfEmployees",
                "ultimateParent",
                "uRL"
            ]); // Use an array of acceptable object key names as a whitelist.
            var jsonStrOfficesContacts, jsonStrBrandsAdvertisers;

            for (i in agency.offices) { // Outer loop for each office
                jsonStrOfficesContacts = Y.JSON.stringify(agency.offices, [
                    "address1",
                    "address2",
                    "address3",
                    "address4",
                    "address5",
                    "agencyID",
                    "faxNumber",
                    "officeID",
                    "postCode",
                    "telephoneNumber",
                    "contacts", // From this point on I am drilling into office[n].contacts data
                    "emailAddress",
                    "firstName",
                    "jobName",
                    "personID",
                    "surName",
                    "title"
                ]);
            }
            jsonStrBrandsAdvertisers = Y.JSON.stringify(brands, [
                "agencyId",
                "brandId",
                "brandName",
                "categoryDescription",
                "dateAmended",
                "defaultSearchName1",
                "defaultSearchName2",
                "advertiser", //brands.advertser
                "activities",
                "additionalInfo",
                "advertiserId",
                "advertiserName",
                "alfRank",
                "cinemaRank",
                "directMailRank",
                "internetRank",
                "nielsenId",
                "notes",
                "numberOfEmployees",
                "outdoorRank",
                "pressRank",
                "radioRank",
                "tVRank"
            ]);

            localStorage.setItem('Agency', null);
            localStorage.setItem('Offices', null);
            localStorage.setItem('Brands', null);

            localStorage.setItem('Agency', jsonStrAgency);
            localStorage.setItem('Offices', jsonStrOfficesContacts);
            localStorage.setItem('Brands', jsonStrBrandsAdvertisers);
        });
        //var objBrands = new Object(ko.mapping.fromJSON(localStorage.getItem('Brands')));

        //    for (i in objBrands._latestValue) {
        //        for (a in objBrands._latestValue[i]) {
        //            if (a == "advertiser") {
        //                objAdvertiser = objBrands._latestValue[i].advertiser; // get advertiser data
        //                objBrands.unshift(objBrands._latestValue[i].advertiser) // unshift it from root
        //                // create temp objects
        //                var tempBrands = ko.toJS(objBrands);
        //                var tempAdvertiser = ko.toJS(objAdvertiser);
        //                brands[i].advertiser = tempAdvertiser;

        //            }
        //        }
        //    }
    }

    function addOffice() {
        //Convert agency observable to object
        var objAgency = ko.toJS(vm.agency);

        var objOffice = {
            address1: " ",
            address2: " ",
            address3: " ",
            address4: " ",
            address5: " ",
            agencyID: " ",
            contacts: [],
            faxNumber: " ",
            officeID: " ",
            postCode: " ",
            telephoneNumber: " ",
        }

        objAgency[0].offices.unshift(objOffice); // Add new object to agency
        vm.agency([ko.mapping.fromJS(objAgency[0])]); //Bind back to KO
    }

    function removeOffice(office) {
        var ID = office.officeID._latestValue;
        agency._latestValue[0].offices.remove(office);
    }

    function addContact(office) { // Passing in object array of agency. We no it contains correct office and agency ID

        // Assign observable data to new variable then remove old
        // variable from mapping
        var objAgency = ko.toJS(agency);
        var officeTableNum;
        //vm.agency.removeAll();

        var agencyID = office.agencyID._latestValue;
        var officeID = office.officeID._latestValue


        // Fill new object with empty strings and related data
        var objContact = {
            agencyID: agencyID,
            emailAddress: "",
            firstName: "",
            jobName: "",
            office: "",
            OfficeID: officeID,
            personID: "",
            surName: "",
            title: "",
            responsibilities: "",
            notes: ""
        }    
        // Splice where office ID match
        for (i in objAgency[0].offices) {
            if (!isNaN(i)) {
                if (objAgency[0].offices[i].officeID === officeID) {
                    // set var for tracking office i.e. office 1, 2, 3
                    officeTableNum = i + 1; // Because of 0 index, add 1
                    objAgency[0].offices[i].contacts.unshift(objContact); // At i remove one object
                }
                else {
                }
            }
        }
        vm.agency([ko.mapping.fromJS(objAgency[0])]);
    }

    function removeContact(contact) {
        for (i in agency._latestValue[0].offices._latestValue) {
            if (isNaN(i)) { // Escape if NaN, otherwise use index valI ha

            }
            else {
                for (ii in agency._latestValue[0].offices._latestValue[i].contacts._latestValue) {
                    agency._latestValue[0].offices._latestValue[i].contacts.remove(contact);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function addBrand() {

        //Convert agency observable to object
        var objAgency = ko.toJS(vm.agency);

        var objBrand = {
            brandName: " ",
            advertiserName: " ",
            aLFRank: " ",
            totalRank: " ",
            cinemaRank: " ",
            directMailRank: " ",
            internetRank: " ",
            outdoorRank: " ",
            pressRank: " ",
            radioRank: " ",
            tVRank: " ",
        }

        objAgency[0].brands.unshift(objBrand); // Add new object to agency
        vm.agency([ko.mapping.fromJS(objAgency[0])]); //Bind back to KO 
    }

    function removeBrand(brand) {
        var ID = brand.brandID._latestValue;
        agency._latestValue[0].brands.remove(brand);
    }
});
```

**Summary**

Want to bind my observable array data to dropdown menu but also have dropdown items available as well.

**Edit**

**New VM**

```
 var vm = { // This is my view model, my functions are bound to it. 
        //These are wired up to my agency view
        activate: activate,
        agency: agency,
        title: 'agency',
        refresh: refresh, // call refresh function which calls get Agencies
        save: save,
        cacheForm: cacheForm,
        addOffice: addOffice,
        removeOffice: removeOffice,
        addBrand: addBrand,
        removeBrand: removeBrand,
        addContact: addContact,
        removeContact: removeContact,
        responsibilityOptions: ['France', 'Germany', 'Spain']
    };
    return vm;
```

**New Binding**

```
 <select data-bind="options: $root.responsibilityOptions, value: responsibility"></select>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Why the downvote? My question is valid and my code is readable.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the options binding for selects.

Documentation is found at: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

Basically you do this:

```
<select data-bind="options: yourArray, value: responsibility"></select>
```

Just replace `yourArray` with whatever you are wanting to populate the dropdown with.

So rather than putting in the options in the HTML, put them in an observableArray and use that in place of `yourArray`

Take a look at this knocked up Fiddle to see if it helps you out: http://jsfiddle.net/r3AA9/

Comment: I have done your suggestion but now every dropdown menu has the first element of my array that I have put into my observableArray. See my post edit for more details.

Comment: make it an observableArray and check

Comment: I have a question. If for my select I don't specify options, shouldn't it just display the value from my observable array? What I am trying to say is value: responsibility comes from the database and if I use <input> it binds the value. But it doesn't display the value when I use <select>

Comment: I personally would do a condition there, so if there is no array then show a regular input, otherwise show the options.  The options bind needs the array specified, so either don't show it, or set the array to only have yours responsibility value in it

Answer (score 0):

this is how i am binding my dropdowns using ko

```
<select data-bind="options: ['DU','IDU','IDU/DU','Former IDU'], value: UserType" class="box-select" />
```

Comment: use this when you have fixed values for your dropdown, if you want to fill from database then let me know